# Using Excel, how can I replace similar text with a one label

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to avoid VBA solutions and I figured this may be something already included in Excel. The issue is that I have a column of data that has similar names  but then have a specific part after it like [product1 academic, product1 scholar], is there a way to get all product1 (ect) cells highlighted and replace with just the text product1?

In General what I would like to be able to do is identify similar groups and replace them with a designated group name.

I would be replacing multiple similar groups.

Comment: Do a find for `product1*` and replace with `product1`?

Comment: do you have a list of the groups, if not what is the rule to know when the group code ends and the specific code begins?

Comment: I was hoping that excel would have some way of identifying similar cells

Comment: Excel is purely logical.  There needs to be rules to how to find the category.  Take for example: `T-Shirt Jedi Small`, `T-Shirt Jedi Large`,`T-Shirt Sith Small`, `T-Shirt Sith Large`  What is/are the category(s) here.  is it `T-Shirt`,`Jedi-Sith` or `Small-Large`, or a combination.  Excel cannot interpolate.  It must have rules to follow.